# Two different results with two methods of numerical integration?

Tags: r, gaussian, numerical-methods

I calculated the integral of the product of a Gaussian density and some function.

First, I did it with the function `int2()` (`rmutil` package).
And then, I did it with Gauss-Hermite points.
The two results I have obtained are different.
Should I consider that the Gauss-Hermite method is the good one and the numerical integration is an approximation ?

I provide below an example :

**1. rmutil::int2()**

```
library(rmutil)

Sig <- matrix (c(0.2^2, 0, 0, 0.8^2), ncol=2)
Mu<- c(2, 0) 


to.integrate <- function(B0, B1) {
  first.int= 1/0.8 * (1.2 * exp(B0 + B1 * 0.5))^(-1/0.8) * gamma(1/0.8) 
  B=matrix(c(B0, B1), ncol=1)
  multi.norm=1 / (2 * pi * det(Sig)^(1/2)) * 
    exp (- 0.5 * t( B - Mu ) %*% solve(Sig) %*%( B - Mu ) )
  return (first.int %*% multi.norm)
}

result_int2 <- int2(to.integrate, a=c(-Inf, -Inf), b=c(Inf, Inf), 
                     eps=1.0e-6, max=16, d=5)
```

**2. Compute multivariate Gaussian quadrature points:**

```
library(statmod)
mgauss.hermite <- function(n, mu, sigma) {
  dm  <- length(mu)
  gh  <- gauss.quad(n, 'hermite')
  gh  <- cbind(gh$nodes, gh$weights)
  idx <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(1:n), dm)))
  pts <- matrix(gh[idx, 1], nrow(idx), dm)
  wts <- apply(matrix(gh[idx, 2], nrow(idx), dm), 1, prod)
  eig <- eigen(sigma) 
  rot <- eig$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(eig$values))
  pts <- t(rot %*% t(pts) + mu)
  return(list(points=pts, weights=wts))
}

nod_wei <- mgauss.hermite(10, mu=Mu, sigma=Sig)
gfun <- function(B0, B1) {
  first.int <- 1/0.8 *(1.2 * exp(B0 + B1 * 0.5))^(-1/0.8)* gamma(1/0.8) 
  return(first.int)
}

result_GH <- sum(gfun(nod_wei$points[, 1], nod_wei$points[, 2]) * nod_wei$weights)/pi

result_int2
result_GH
```

Comment: I notice that you used `max=16`. Sixteen steps from -Inf to Inf seems kind of sparse.  Did you try increasing `max`?

Comment: I tried to change the `max` value, but it does not change anything. According to the values of the variances in the matrix of variances-covariance (Sig), the difference between `int2` and the Gauss-Hermite method tends to increase with higher values of variances.

Comment: Just want to point out that both methods here are from the *numerical integration family* (as opposed to, say, symbolic evaluation-type methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake came from the way the points were calculated in the `mgauss.hermite` function.

I changed the decomposition of the Sigma matrix for a Cholesky decomposition with a multiplication by square root of 2.
And the results of the two methods became very similar.
Below is the correction of the `mgauss.hermite` function

```
mgauss.hermite <- function(n, mu, sigma) {
  dm  <- length(mu)
  gh  <- gauss.quad(n, 'hermite')
  gh  <- cbind(gh$nodes, gh$weights)
  idx <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(1:n),dm)))
  pts <- matrix(gh[idx,1],nrow(idx),dm)
  wts <- apply(matrix(gh[idx,2],nrow(idx),dm), 1, prod)
  rot <- 2.0**0.5*t(chol(sigma))
  pts <- t(rot %*% t(pts) + mu)
  return(list(points=pts, weights=wts))
}
```